# PHP developer learning RoR. Should I learn RoR with an e-book written for Rails 2.0.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been working with PHP for years. Today, I started to learn Ruby on Rails and found an ebook that suits me. The e-book is called `Rails for PHP Developers`. It is written in 2008, so it covers PHP 5.2 plus Rails 2.0.2.

The only reason I picked this book is, it both explains PHP and Ruby on Rails source. Like, how we create a class or method on PHP, and how it is like on Ruby, what is different etc. Since I already know PHP side, I can easily understand what's going on and adapt myself to ruby syntax.

However, `PHP 5.2 is pretty old`. PHP evolved so much in last few years, so 5.2 feels like ancient for me. I also used `Laravel framework` for the past few months, which was created by `Taylor Otwell with inspiration of Ruby on Rails` framework. I've watched `Rails for Zombies` screencasts too, and can honestly tell Laravel is a perfect Rails clone. It feels like they're the same thing. "Yeah yeah, ActiveRecord thing. I know that already."

With that said; I'm not sure if there are huge differences between RoR 2.0.2 and RoR 4.0.0.
Should I keep reading this e-book or RoR 2.0.0 very old with many missing important features? (That is two major releases difference.) If so, what can you suggest to me?

Also, if there are other great resources for learning RoR, please let me know.

Ps. Help this PHP guy make the correct choice and jump-in to the Ruby world.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ seems to be the goto place for people starting rails.

Comment: you can learn from anything but I would start with 3 a minimum preferable 4 as it the latest version.  But whichever guide/book you use, make sure that you use the version of rails it covers..

Comment: If you don't know Ruby, at least moderately well, you should take several months just to work with it alone to become familiar with its fundamentals and the ideas of introspection and dynamic definitions. Otherwise Rails is going to appear to be so much black magic and voodoo to you. Rails is full of very advanced Ruby. "[Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke's_three_laws)" -- Arthur Clarke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can start from `rails 3.x.x` directly, or even `rails 4.x.x`.

follow this tutorial.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

for `rails 4.x.x`

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0

Comment: $ rails -v "Rails 3.2.13". Is it fine to learn or should I learn Rails 4 (since somehow I installed 4 on my dev env)

Comment: yes that is fine and still supported.

Comment: @Imaqtpie as i said you can start with rails 4 too(follow this)

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0

Comment: This plus Rails for Zombies screencasts got me going already. Everything feels very similar and I already liked using closures for .each method. Bye bye foreach($something as $key => $value).

Answer (score 1):

a good tutorial for rails beginners is http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

also, there are A LOT of differences between rails 2 and rails 4, in the framework itself and the ruby version required to run it.
For example, ruby 2 doesn't have features that were added in rails 3 but then renamed or removed in rails 4..

Rails 2 is pretty much end-of-life, and you should at least focus on rails 3 if not rails 4

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste your time with Rails 2

Along with the other answers, try this interactive learning approach with Rails for Zombies

http://railsforzombies.org